# Visualizing the "Impossible Trinity"

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, currency, data-request

I would like to create a data viz to show, in one chart, where some of the major economies are on the trilemma. It won't be perfect, but I'm just looking for a rough characterization. For my data viz to work, all three need to be **quantitative** not qualitative. Some bits I have already tracked down quantitative measures:

- Capital mobility
- Independent monetary policy: [There's an index for this](https://www.ijcb.org/journal/ijcb14q1a6.pdf)
- Fixed exchange rate: [The wiki can be an ordinal variable for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_exchange_rate_regime)

So I'm stuck at capital mobility. I have googled "capital mobility" and related terms but I'm a bit skeptical of the results.

### Question

If we can't retrieve perfect, capital controls data, what might we consider as an effective substitute that is fairly easy to scrape from the public domain and is still **quantitative**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper *Capital Control Measures: A New Dataset* by Andrés Fernández, Michael W. Klein, Alessandro Rebucci, Martin Schindler,
and Martín Uribe ([link](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/wp/2015/wp1580.pdf)) has an index of capital controls.

From footnote 8:

> The dataset is publicly available for download at the National Bureau of Economic Research website
> (https://www.nber.org/data/international-finance/) or at request from the authors.

The link seems to be broken, but you could write to the authors and ask for the data.